# Darts on a ruler probability

Tags: probability

If two points are selected at random on an interval from 0 to 1.5 inches, what is
the probability that the distance between them is less than or equal to 1/4"?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have some thoughts on the problem? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the square with corners $(0,0)$, $(1.5.0)$, $(1.5,1.5)$, and $(0,1.5)$.

Imagine the points are chosen one at a time. Let random variable $X$ be the first chosen point, and $Y$ the second chosen point. We are invited to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,1.5]$ and independent. (Uniform distribution is highly implausible with real darts.)

Then $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed in the square just drawn.

Consider the two lines $y=x+\frac{1}{4}$ and $y=x-\frac{1}{4}$.

The two points are within $\frac{1}{4}$ inch from each other if the random variable $(X,Y)$ falls in the part of our square between the two lines.

Call that part of the square $A$. Then our probability is the area of $A$ divided by the area of the whole square.

**Remark:** It is easier to find first the area of the part of the square which is **not** in $A$. This consists of two isosceles right triangles with legs $\frac{5}{4}$, so their combined area is $\frac{25}{16}$. The area of the whole square is $\frac{9}{4}$, so the area of $A$ is $\frac{11}{16}$.

Thus our probability is $\dfrac{\frac{11}{16}}{\frac{9}{4}}$.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, all of these responses helped change the way I approach these problems.

Comment: @Josh: Note that all of us went instantly to the geometry. Geometry is critical in problems about uniformly distributed random variables. But it is also of great help elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the points are selected independently and using the uniform distribution on $[0, 1.5]$.  If you are unfamiliar with these terms you are probably assuming them implicitly and I wouldn't worry about it.  What I would do is draw a square 1.5 units on each side and draw the subset of the square of points $(x,y)$ with $|x-y| \leq 1/4$.  This region will be a hexagon.  Then divide the area of the hexagon by the area of the whole square.

Remark:

It looks like I am competing with another respondent!  I just read his suggestion, and I echo it: find the area of what is NOT in the hexagon, and subtract it from the square, instead of finding the area of the hexagon directly.  Since I stole from his answer, feel free to accept his instead of mine.

Answer (score 0):

The square $S=\{(x,y) | x,y \in [0, \frac{3}{2}] \}$ has area $(\frac{3}{2})^2$. The area $\Delta= \{(x,y) \in S \, |\,  |x-y| > \frac{1}{4} \}$ can be easily rearranged to be a square with area $(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{4})^2$. Hence the chance of landing in $S \setminus  \Delta$ is $\frac{(\frac{3}{2})^2-(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{4})^2}{(\frac{3}{2})^2} = 1 - (1-\frac{1}{6})^2 = \frac{11}{36}$.