# A geometric probability question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, geometric-probability

> Find the probability of distance of two points ,which are selected in $[0,a]$ closed interval, is less than $ka$ $k \lt 1$

What did I write :

$P(A)$ = (Area measure of set $A$)/(Area measure of set $\Omega$)

The sample space $\Omega = \{(x,y) :  0\le x \le a , 0 \le y \le a \}$

Probability set $A=\{(x,y) : |x-y|\lt ka\}$

Measure of $\Omega$ = $a.a=a^2$

I think I should calculate the area of the rectangle between two lines $y=x+ka$ and $y=x-ka$ and bounded with points $(-a,-ka)$,  $(a,ka)$,  $(-ka,-a)$ and $(ka,a)$

But I cannot obtain the true answer which is $k(2-k)$

Could someone please fix me please?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The distribution of the distance between two points, uniformly and independently sampled in an interval, has been considered in a number of previous Questions. For example, [Darts on a ruler probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352698/darts-on-a-ruler-probability) asks about the case $k=1/6$, and the method of solution given there is applicable more generally.  The result there $11/36$ agrees with your "true answer" formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The region of $|y-x| \le ka$ looks similar to the picture that I have attached. We just have to use the total area to subtract away the area of the area of the two triangles.

$$\frac{a^2 - 2\cdot \frac12 (a-ka)^2}{a^2}=1-(1-k)^2=k(2-k)$$

Remark about your attempt:

$x$ or $y$ won't take negative values.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I cannot see the image could you please share it from another site?

Comment: [desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6rl6xrcheb)

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

We need to find the measure of $A$, which is given by
\begin{align}
\int_A dx dy = \int_0^a \int_{\max(y-ka,0)}^{min(y+ka,a)} dx dy = \int_0^a \min(y+ka,a) - \max(y-ka,0) \, dy.
\end{align}
Note that
\begin{align}
\int_0^a \min(y+ka,a) \, dy = \int_0^{a-ka} y+ka \, dy + \int_{a-ka}^a a \, dy.
\end{align}
Can you proceed?

Comment: Thanks but I prefer the other solution it is easier

Comment: Haha i know :D maybe you need this trick to integrate over a min some day ;)

Comment: thanks when I need I will remember your answer :)